# Integrating Factor: DE Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this question:

[image]

Can someone please explain the solution below, especially why the integrating factor is $e^{3x/2}$:

[image]

Comment: Do you know what the integrating factor is and how to find it?

Comment: @Kaster No not really

Comment: Here you go - [Integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step should be obvious, since the initial value problem states that $y(0)=4$, then in some neighbourhood of $x=0$ we introduce $$w(x)=y^{3/2}(x),$$ which allows to write the differential equation as
$$\frac 23 w'(x)+w(x)=1,\quad w(0)=8.$$
This falls into a quite general category of linear ODEs with constant coefficients: say, we want to solve
$$z'(x)+az(x)=b(x),$$
then we can multiply both parts of this equation by $e^{ xa}$ in order to obtain $$(e^{ xa}z(x))'= e^{xa}b(x).$$

Now on the left we have a derivative of the unknown function, and on the right - a know function, hence we are able to solve it.

In more general case, you need to study the characteristic polynomial of the linear ODE with constant coefficients. [This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29) should be a good start.